# Take someone under your wing/wings

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

> He took me under his wing/wings and taught me everything I know.

Are both **wing** and **wings** proper usage?

Answer (score 1):

The established idiom is ***take someone under one's wing*** ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-someone-under-your-wing)).

If you look on the internet, this is the unanimous use, too.